# Command pattern with linked tree structure (using pointers)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, undo-redo

I am developing an editor for some kind of binary tree structure and I need to have an undo function. I thought about using the command pattern to achieve this. However, I was yet unable to find a way to use the command pattern with my binary tree structure.

The binary tree structure is made up via pointers. So a node knows its parent and its children. When I now want to add a node I would construct a `NodeAdd` object with the parent as parameter and pass it to the `UndoStack`. In order to remove an existing node a `NodeRemove` object would be passed to the `UndoStack` with a pointer to the `Node` as parameter. Both, the `NodeAdd` and `NodeRemove` would have to implement `undo()` and `redo()` (where `redo()` is called when the object is put on the `UndoStack`).

The problem I am facing is, dealing with the situation when a node removal and then the addition of this same node should be undone:

1. redo NodeAdd
2. redo NodeRemove
3. undo NodeRemove
4. undo NodeAdd

Once the *redo NodeRemove* is executed the `Node` object is destroyed. In the *undo NodeRemove* a new `Node` object can be constructed again, but *undo NodeAdd* could not be executed as it does not have the pointer to the newly constructed `Node`.

I think I am trying to use the command pattern in the wrong way. I probably should destroy or construct the `Node` objects rather within the commands' constructor/destructor than within `undo()`/`redo()`. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this with this kind of structure and all examples and advices I could find are related to text editing or editing something where you have not a dynamic structure with pointers.

Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to have your `Command` objects refer to their operands by some unique identifier (say an index represented as a `size_t`) instead of by memory address which, as you've discovered, can fluctuate.

Then, by maintaining an `unordered_map< size_t, Node* >` somewhere (say a static member of `Node` for example), your `Command` objects can obtain the current embodiment of a given `Node` and add/remove/manipulate it as necessary.

Comment: I agree that this is a option. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The command pattern is probably not sufficient for the undo. For  undo, you should use the memento pattern.

Comment: If I understood the memento pattern, I need to keep copies of the graph for every state. Using the command pattern I would only store the actual changes between two states.

Although creating a copy of the whole graph would avoid the problem I have described, I am curious whether there is way to solve the issue and keep only track of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Patterns can be combined, even within themselves.  Give your Commands both an execute method and an undo method.  When a Command is invoked put an instance into a two way Chain of Responsibility, have an undo and redo direction and methods.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to point out. What do you exactly mean by putting _an instance into a two way chain of responsibility_? So far I only recognise a rough explanation of the command pattern.